# Python - Creating an .ini or config file in the user's home directory

Tags: python-2.7, config, ini

This is probably a simple answer but I'm **really** new when it comes to Python. I've been given existing code, and I'm trying to create a config file for it, whereas previously it had everything hardcoded. I want to have a `default` config that's with the source code, but then have the program create a copy of that config file in the user's home directory (ex. ~/.config) when they run it for the first time. That way they can edit the file in their home directory rather than edit the source code. (At least I've been told that's what's best.) I'm really bad with syntax and whatnot but I know it should be something like:

```
try import ~/.config/cfg.ini
```

except if file doesn't exist, import defaultconfig and create a copy of defaultconfig called `cfg.ini` in `~/.config` (the directory ~/.config would have to be created then too)

Currently I just have `config.py` with my source code and then I use import config, and config.(variable name) when I need the value.

I know this is formatted poorly, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

It's generally not possible to import source code from a different directory structure in Python. You should use a `configparser` to read and write data.

I divided the program into two files, first you run `write_default_config.py` to generate the default config. Then on every invocation of `main.py` the script checks for the existence of a user config file, and otherwise copies it over from the source directory after creating the necessary folder.

**write_default_config.py:**

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.add_section('section')
config['section']['setting_1'] = "hello"
config['section']['setting_2'] = "goodbye"

with open("default_config.ini", 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

**main.py:**

```
import os, shutil, configparser

user_config_dir = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/.config/Nick_H"
user_config = user_config_dir + "/user_config.ini"

if not os.path.isfile(user_config):
    os.makedirs(user_config_dir, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copyfile("default_config.ini", user_config)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(user_config)

print(config['section']['setting_1'])
print(config['section']['setting_2'])
```

You always have read and write config data using sections. This is a hassle if you don't feel like you need section but there seems to be no way around it.

My example writes two strings and then prints them just to show how things works, you should replace this with your own information.

Comment: Okay thanks, but this creates default_config.ini in the same place as the scripts, correct? If that's the case, this is all unnecessary since I already have a config file in the same folder as my scripts, and that works okay. I'm pretty sure that with other, more professional software, they create a config file or folder in your home directory when you either install them or run them for the first time. I'd like to do the same because we're trying to keep people from modifying things in the folder where the source code is.

Comment: If you don't want to use `configparser`, then pick out the code for copying a file and creating folders, and then modify your code to always get its config data from the user's file. You are still not going to be able to use Python's `import` on a file located outside of the source tree, though.

Answer (score 1):

For other googlers looking for a way to safely/reliably place a file in the user's home directory across various operating systems, here ya go

```
import os

filePath = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.configFile'

def write(text: str):
    with open(filePath, 'w+') as file:
        file.write(text)

def read():
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()
```

Put that in a file named `config.py`

Use it like so

```
from . import config

config.write('some stuff')
print(config.read())
>>> 'some stuff'
```

You'll want to flesh this out as suits your program. Note that by default this will completely overwrite the file every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found useful the answer of Harald, anyway I found unnecessary to have a default_config.ini considering I already have the info of how the default file is inside my code.
I then slightly modified the code to check if there is already a config file, and in case these is not it creates a new one with the default parameters.
I also integrated everything in the main.

**"main.py"**

```
import os, shutil, configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('settings')
config['settings']['param_1'] = "Hi"
config['settings']['param_2'] = "15"

user_config_dir = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/.config/Your_Forder"
user_config = user_config_dir + "/user_config.ini"

if not os.path.isfile(user_config):
    os.makedirs(user_config_dir, exist_ok=True)
    with open(user_config, 'w') as f:
        config.write(f)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(user_config)
```

hope could help